Extracting multiple archives with WinRAR where some are missing parts
I have a folder with a few thousand rar and zip files. Some are separated into multiple parts and others are not. My goal is to extract all of the files. The files are large and I expect this may take a several days. Complicating things is that for some of the archives with multiple parts, one of the parts is missing.
I've been extracting the files by highlighting several files in Windows Explorer, right click and select WinRAR > Extract files... and letting the extraction run overnight. The problem is that the process is halted when WinRAR encounters a missing part. When this happens, WinRAR prompts me to select the missing file with a dialog that looks like this:
Next volume is required
My question is: Is there any kind of setting in WinRAR where I can tell it that if it encounters an archive with a missing part, to just skip trying to extract that archive and move to the next one?

This question is similar to: How to extract multipart rar with missing parts?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
